# Add columns result of a join in Flask-admin view

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I've two tables with a relation one-to-more.

- People: id, name, surname
- Events: id, desc, date, personid

Personid is a foreign key to People table.

In flask-admin using this :

```
class PeopleAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    [...]
    column_auto_select_related = True
    inline_models = (Events,)
```

I can have a form to create/update new people row with a very nice widget that shows the possibility also to add directly new events for the context-person.

I would like to know if this "inline" data (pratically a on-the-fly join by Id) can be visibile also in the main view, in other words I would expect a list of People rows in this way:

```
Id | Name | Surname | Events
1  | John | Doe     | event desc 01/01/1980, Event desc 02/03/1987
2  | Joe  | Brown   | event desc 10/01/1977
3  | Mark | Nest    | event desc 01/09/1984, Event desc 02/03/1988, Event desc 12/12/2004
```

Answer (score -1):

func.group_concat (GROUP_CONCAT in mysql)

is the answer :)